# Jquery/ Javascript Print issue with Internet explorer 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, printing

when I print an HTML element such as a div or a table with Internet Explorer 11 i couldn't see printing preview. In effect printing process not start at all.

I used this javascript to print. With Chrome and Firefox work fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function printData(){
var divToPrint=document.getElementById("tableId");
newWin= window.open("");
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
}


</script>
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

IE is somewhat weird with the `window.print()` method.
I suggest to go for `document.execCommand` when in IE, as in:

```
function printData(){
    var divToPrint=document.getElementById("tableId");
    newWin= window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    if (!! navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/gi)) {
        newWin.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
    } else {
        newWin.print();
    }
    newWin.close();
}
```